# How can I convert hexadecimal to decimal numbers in calc of Emacs?

Tags: emacs, calc

How can I convert hexadecimal to decimal numbers in Emacs calc?
For example, if I enter `FF`, I want it to convert it to `255`.

UPDATE:  How do I get the reverse operation, turn base 10 to base 16?

Answer (score 41):

You can enter any number in the format `<base>#<number>`.  Example: `16#FF` is immediately converted to `255`.

For the reverse, you need to set the output display mode.  In this example, `d` `r` `16` <kbd>RET</kbd> sets the display to base 16.  Set it to base 10 to get the default behaviour again.

By the way, you can also Read The Fine Manual<sup>TM</sup>: [GNU Emacs Calc Manual](http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/calc/calc_toc.html).

Comment: `C-x * q 10#255` will show 255 in decimal, hex, octal, and binary in the mini buffer.

Comment: @DavorCubranic this works only if the display radix was decimal to begin with. If it is e.g. binary, it will only show binary.

Comment: I stumbled on this when trying out your hint. My calc was set to binary display...

Answer (score 14):

[Svante](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1859798/how-can-i-convert-hexadecimal-to-decimal-numbers-in-calc-of-emacs/1859918#1859918) answered your question, but I'd like to add that the Radix Display Mode change has a [quicker keystroke](http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/calc/calc_161.html):

- Show in hexidecimal mode: `d` `6`
- Show in decimal mode: `d` `0`

Answer (score 7):

Of course you could type `16#FF` to enter `0xFF`, but there is a more convenient way.

**The other option:**

1. change the display radix to hex with `d 6`
2. then enter all the hex numbers you want by prefixing them with a `#` like `#FF` and `<enter>`. (The `#` means interpret number with given display radix)
3. After this, change the display radix back to decimal with `d 0`.

*Note:* A number entered without `#` always inserts a decimal number.
*Note2:* This also works the other way round.

**Negative Values:**
Now lets say you have a 8-bit system and you want to know how decimal -3 is stored in this systems RAM.

1. switch word size: `b w 8`
2. enter dec -3 by typing `3 n` and `<enter>`
3. set display radix to hex with two's complement notation: `O d 6`. (The `O` as Option is important to enable two's complement.)

*Note:* you see `16##FD`. Two `#` means it is signed and the value stored in RAM is `0xFD`

The above stuff works also with `d 2`, `d 8` (as shortcuts for bin and oct) and other possible display radixes from 2 to 36 (`d r <radix-number>`).

This info is taken from the [Emacs Calc Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/calc/Radix-Modes.html).

Comment: upvoted since you noted that you need to start with a `#`

Comment: When I try to paste a hex value (with no leading `0x`) right after `#` I get `[Bad format]`, but it's easy enough to do #` (pound backtick) to get to the line editor and paste the hex there.